# Weird shading artifacts in ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, color

Drawing certain shapes in ContourPlot3D gets these weird little shady artifacts with any colorfunction other than the default:

```
ContourPlot3D[1/Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2],{x,-1,1},{y,0,1},{z,-1,1},Ticks->None,Contours->Range[5],ColorFunction->"TemperatureMap"]
```

gives

[image: weird shading]

while the same thing with the default colors gives smoothly shaded, pretty contours.

I see a lot of articles about weird plotting artifacts, but I haven't found any about this one in particular.  Any thoughts on how to get rid of the artifacts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some reason, the `VertexColors` of the recursively computed vertices are set incorrectly. I think this should be reported to Wolfram Support.

Anyways, here is a quick fix:

```
f = {x, y, z} \[Function] 1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
g = ContourPlot3D[
 f[x, y, z], {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
 Ticks -> None, 
 Contours -> Range[5], 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"
 ];
pos = Position[g, _GraphicsComplex][[1]];
GC = Extract[g, pos];
colpos = Append[#, 2] & /@ Position[GC, VertexColors -> _][[{-1}]];
GC = ReplacePart[GC, 
   colpos -> List @@@ (ColorData["TemperatureMap"] /@ Rescale[f @@@ GC[[1]]])
   ];
ReplacePart[g, pos -> GC]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Henrik Schumacher's answer is great and the basis of this extension.  He deserves 100% of the credit for this (and no blame for any errors I've introduced below).

I am extending it merely because his answer fixes the MWE given in the OP, but I want now to automate it and generalize to predefined and user-defined color functions (of one variable... multivariable ones are left as an exercise to anybody interested ;) ).  Here's my amateur attempt to do so:

```
PrettyContourPlot3D[o__]:=Module[
 {g=ContourPlot3D[o],
  f={o}[[1]],
  args={o}[[2;;4,1]],
  cfp=Position[{o},ColorFunction],
  cf,gcp,GC,cp
 },
 If[Length[cfp]>0,
  cf={o}[[cfp[[1,1]],2]];
  If[StringQ[cf],cf=ColorData[cf]];
  gcp=Position[g,_GraphicsComplex][[1]];
  GC=Extract[g, gcp];
  cp=Append[#,2]&/@Position[GC,VertexColors->_][[{-1}]];
  GC=ReplacePart[
   GC, 
   cp->List@@@(ColorConvert[#,"RGB"]&/@cf/@Rescale[
    f/.{args[[1]]->#1,args[[2]]->#2,args[[3]]->#3}&@@@GC[[1]]])
  ];
  ReplacePart[g, gcp -> GC],
  g
 ]
]
```

Comment: I'll admit I find StackEchange's rules here confusing... responses are not allowed in "Answers" since they belong in comments, but comments are not allowed to be long... are long responses simply verboten?

Comment: Since you've extended Henrik's answer on your own, I would say it deserves to be a full answer.

Comment: I second that...